# SSIS Add date to file name when moving

Tags: ssis

I have a csv in a file location that I am trying to move and rename to another location.

Currently I have a for loop with a File System Task in it.

The For Loop looks for all csv files in a location which is `@ProcessingFilePath`

I write the name and extension to a variable called `@ProcessedFileName`.

I also have another variable called `@ArchiveFilePath`, this is where I want to move my file.

So I have a file connection manager with an expression of

```
@ProcessingFilePath + "\\" + @ProcessedFileName
```

Then in the file system task  - the source connection will be the file connection manager above.

The destination I am trying to create another variable which will be something like `@ArchiveFilePathandName`, I've got the following expression for that (which i've pinched from another site).

```
@[User::ArchiveFilePath] 
+ SUBSTRING( @[User::ProcessedFileName] , 1 , FINDSTRING( @[User::ProcessedFileName],".",1) - 1 ) 
+ "-" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) Month( @[System::StartTime] )
+ (DT_STR, 4, 1252) Year( @[System::StartTime] )
+ SUBSTRING( @[User::ProcessedFileName] , FINDSTRING( @[User::ProcessedFileName],".",1) , LEN( @[User::ProcessedFileName] ) )
```

But I get an error saying:

> The length -1 is not valid for Function SUBSTRING. The length
>   parameter cannot be negative. Change the length parameter to zero or a
>   positive value.

I have no idea what to do here. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: You shouldn't use code from a site without knowing what it does. The FINDSTRING function isn't finding anything, thus returning -1 and the SUBSTRING fails because there is no -1 position in a string. This means you have a filename that doesn't have an extension, since you are looking for a dot ".".

Comment: So is there a better approach please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have files without a dot in it's name. The `FINDSTRING` function returns a -1 and the subsequent `SUBSTRING` fails because it can't start at -1.

A solution would be checking if the file has a dot beforehand to prevent the `SUBSTRING` altogether. You can do this with the ternary operator `? :`.

```
FINDSTRING(@[User::ProcessedFileName],".",1) > 0 ?

    @[User::ArchiveFilePath] 
    + SUBSTRING( @[User::ProcessedFileName] , 1 , FINDSTRING( @[User::ProcessedFileName],".",1) - 1 ) 
    + "-" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) Month( @[System::StartTime] ) + (DT_STR, 4, 1252) Year( @[System::StartTime] )
    + SUBSTRING( @[User::ProcessedFileName] , FINDSTRING( @[User::ProcessedFileName],".",1) , LEN( @[User::ProcessedFileName] ) ) 

    :

    @[User::ArchiveFilePath] 
    + @[User::ProcessedFileName]
    + "-" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) Month( @[System::StartTime] ) + (DT_STR, 4, 1252) Year( @[System::StartTime] )
```

Expressions are really a weakness of SSIS and this is a good example why.

Comment: Still get the same error I'm afraid. I've worked out another way to do it